# Can a Vuex module watch another Vuex module?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Can Vuex modules watch the state of other modules, and trigger actions consequently?

For example, let's consider the following case:

`store.js`

```
import time from './store/time' ;
import position from './store/position' ;

const store = new Vuex.Store
(
    {
        modules:
        {
            time,
            position
        }    
    }
) ;
```

`store/time.js`

```
export default
{

    namespaced: true,

    state:
    {
        time: new Date()
    },

    getters:
    {
        time: (aState) => aState.time
    },

    mutations:
    {

        setTime (aState, aTime)
        {
            aState.time = aTime ;
        }

    }

} ;
```

`store/position.js`

```
export default
{

    namespaced: true,

    state:
    {
        positions: {}
    },

    getters:
    {
        positions: aState => aState.positions
    },

    mutations:
    {

        setPositions (aState, aPositionArray)
        {
            aState.positions = aPositionArray ;
        }

    },

    actions:
    {

        fetchPositionsAtTime ({ dispatch, commit, rootGetters }, { time })
        {
            // Fetch positions at given time from the server
            // commit('setPositions', ...)
        }

    }

} ;
```

Ideally, I would like the position module to watch the time module, and re-fetch the positions (i.e. trigger `fetchPositionsAtTime`) as soon as the time state changes.

Of course, I could add a dispatch to the `setTime` mutation to trigger a position module action, but I believe going the other way around (i.e. watching) would be more elegant (as many more modules may require time).

Any solution to this? (without using `Vue Component` of course, that is the whole point)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the store instance's `watch` method to watch the `time` state and then dispatch the `fetchPositionsAtTime` action whenever that `time` value changes:

```
store.watch((state) => state.time.time, (val) => {
  store.dispatch('position/fetchPositionsAtTime', { time: val })
});
```

If you don't want to watch the state directly you can also watch a getter like so:

```
store.watch((state, getters) => getters['time/time'], (val) => {
  store.dispatch('position/fetchPositionsAtTime', { time: val })
});
```

[Here's a link to the api documentation for Vuex.Store instances.](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html)

---

Here's an example:

```js
const time = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    time: new Date()
  },
  getters: {
    time: (aState) => aState.time
  },
  mutations: {
    setTime (aState, aTime) {
      aState.time = aTime ;
    }
  }
};

const position = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    positions: {}
  },
  getters: {
    positions: aState => aState.positions
  },
  mutations: {
    setPositions (aState, aPositionArray) {
      aState.positions = aPositionArray ;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPositionsAtTime ({ dispatch, commit, rootGetters }, { time }) {
      let value = rootGetters['position/positions'].value || 0;
      commit('setPositions', { value: ++value });
    }
  }
};

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: { time, position }    
});

store.watch((state) => state.time.time, (val) => {
  store.dispatch('position/fetchPositionsAtTime', { time: val })
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  methods: {
    setTime() {
      this.$store.commit('time/setTime', new Date());
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  time: {{ $store.getters['time/time'] }}
  <br>
  position: {{ $store.getters['position/positions'] }}
  <br>
  <button @click="setTime">Change time</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution indeed, thanks!
Would this also work watching a getter and not the state directly?

Comment: Thanks! In my case, to use the getters, I had to do store.watch(() => store.getters['time/time'], ...) because Typescript didn't allow me to use (state, getters) as function parameters...